# How to Get net core 3.0 self contained extraction location

Tags: c#, .net-core

How do I get the Location of the folder that the Self-Contained exe creates? i know that folder exist in this path:

```
%temp%/.net/appname/random name/...
```

but i want to get that location with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Assembly.Location Gets the full path or UNC location of the loaded file that contains the manifest.

So, you can try:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
```

Some Resources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly?view=netcore-3.1
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_Assembly_Location